# ERROR: $rvm_ruby_string is not set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

That is the error message I am getting when running 'rvm gemset list_all' within the scope of my pre-existing gemsets, after having upgraded to RVM 1.7.2 and Ruby 1.9.2-p290 (from 1.9.2-p180).

There is another error message produced also:

```
ERROR: Unknown ruby interpreter string component: '<my-home-dir>/.rvm/gems/ruby'
```

Any idea what is causing these errors?

They only occur when I run the list_all command in a pre-existing gemset.  They do not occur when I create a new gemset, or when I run the command under Ruby 1.9.2-p290 without a gemset.

Thanks!

Btw, I'm running OSX 10.6.7.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. did you find a solution? If not I'll post here if I come up with something

Answer (score 0):

I got around this error by removing the gemset(s) that I'd created in new new 1.9.2:

```
rvm gemset delete mysite
```

Navigating back to the home directory with 'cd', then specifying I'd like to use the new ruby:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

and creating the gemset again:

```
rvm gemset create mysite
```

Now when I run list_all, I no longer get the warnings you describe.

At a guess... I might say that this was caused by creating the gemset from within a directory with a .rvmrc file... however, that's a real newbie guess so please correct me if I'm wrong people...

Hope that helps for you too!

Stu